# [Smarty, and maybe doctrine]

Tags: doctrine, foreach, smarty

I'hv got a problem when I am using foreach in smarty,
an array with 2 item was loop in a foreach, but the result is it loop 3 time.

I use doctrine to get a list of review by a user from database

> Doctrine_Core::getTable('review')->findByUser($userId);

then I assign it to smarty and loop in foreach:

> {foreach from=$reviewList item=review}
>
> ```
>   <p>User {$review.User.name} said: {$review.content}</p>
> ```
>
> {/foreach}

However the result is e.g.:

> User Joe said: yoyo
>
> User Mary said: hihi
>
> User said:

Please notice that the extra row doesn't get anything from the array.

I have checked that there is only 2 record in database, and I have count the $reviewList by count($reviewList), the result is also 2.
When I insert one more record to database, the forloop also loop extra one time.
Can anyone tell me why this happen? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should filter the empty line:

```
{foreach from=$reviewList item=review}{if $review.User.name}
  <p>User {$review.User.name} said: {$review.content}</p>
{/if}{/foreach}
```